# Facebook Android Checkins

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-checkins

Ok so I have been researching the facebook api and Noticed that they released a new SDK. I have been trying to implement a checkin to a known place id.

I have seen posts that use the `facebook.request("me/checkins", params, "POST");` to checkin using the facebook instance.

I realize that checkins are depreciated and that i should be posting with a location/place id instead. The problem comes when i want to search for all of my friends that have been to that location within that past 24 hours. I do not want to filter through all of my friends posts to retrieve the ones with my known locations.

With checkins i simply made a call to the placeid/checkins and filtered out all checkins that were too old to matter.

Has anyone gotten checkins to work using `Request`?
Is there a graphpath that will allow me to post a checkin to a place? me/checkins perhaps?

I am trying to use something like `Request(session, "me/checkins", parameters, POST)` But i have been unsuccessful so far.

If there is not a way to do this with Session and Request then do Facebook and asyncFacebook runners work well with SSO?Can they be mixed?

Comment: What permissions have you requested before posting the checkin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code to post a checkin.

```
params.putString("place", "166793820034304");
params.putString("message", "checking in "
params.putString("coordinates", "{\"longitude\":-122.1477782,\"latitude\":37.48566}");
Request.Callback callback6 = new Request.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        // response here
    }
};
Request request6 = new Request(session, "me/checkins", params, HttpMethod.POST, callback6);
RequestAsyncTask task6 = new RequestAsyncTask(request6);
task6.execute();
```

Comment: This works thankyou. I forgot to post when i solved but this is the same format that i used to post a checkin.